# Version grails domain class by DateTime

Tags: grails, versioning, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I'd like to version a grails domain class by DateTime such that:

- each primary ID + DateTime property results in a new DB row (i.e. a new DB row per version)
- the newest version can be found without having to specify the DateTime value

My knowledge of grails is a little limited right now and I don't understand how I can achieve this.

Consider the following domain class as an example:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime

class Page {
    String pageId
    DateTime theVersion
    String content

    static constraints = {
        pageId(nullable:false, blank:false, unique:true, matches:"[a-zA-Z\\._-]+")
        content(nullable:false, blank:false)
    }

    static mapping = {
        content(type:"text")
    }
}
```

- What changes are needed to ensure a new DB row is inserted per version?
   I'm assuming some form of constraint is required such that pageId+theVersion is unique but I don't know how to express this in the GORM DSL.
- How might I get the most recent version without knowing the relevant DateTime value?
  I'm envisaging something like:
  `Page.findByPageIdAndTheVersionLessThanEquals('uniquePageId', new DateTime())` 
  I expect this would find many objects not just one. I'd like to be able to also express the equivalent of `ORDER BY theVersion DESC LIMIT 0,1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Just create the new versions with `new Page()`, not with `get()` - a new record will be inserted.

To assure uniqueness, put into constraints: 
`theVersion(unique: 'pageId')`

- `Page.findByPageId(pageId, [sort: 'theVersion', order: 'desc', max: 1])`
- You can utilize Grails' [`dateCreated` implicit timestamping feature](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.5.1%20Events%20and%20Auto%20Timestamping) - [it will even work with joda-time plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/joda-time).
- OTOH, why don't you utilize Grails' built-in `version` field? It provides you some features out of box and takes care for optimistic locking.

Comment: Thanks Victor! I wasn't aware of the implicit timestamping feature, that looks like a good option. Can I query on dateCreated without there being an explicit property, such as Page.findByPageId(pageId, [sort: 'dateCreated', order: 'desc', max: 1])?

Comment: Sure, it's an ordinary field. BTW, use `grails console` or this: http://grails.org/plugin/console - it will allow you to test code in runtime environment. This will get you answers to questions like this in a moment.